# How do we compare selected fields of two rows with characters

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to compare only a particular section of a data in each row from different sources. Below is the data i have,

```
seq_id  ID  SOURCE  Cell name   TABLE NAME
1   CT01    SRC1    0097023AE5-557-0182726742-BDCOR-__A [121913] A Table info 20190116 CC
2   CT01    SRC1    0002019609-560-0171464877-MORTR-AAA [121915] AAA Table info 20190116 CC
3   CT01    SRC1    0002018668-560-0171465297-MORTR-AAA [121915] AAA Table info 20190116 CC
4   CT01    SRC1    0003117609-327-0193160029-MORTR-AAA [121915] AAA Table info 20190116 CC
5   CT01    SRC1    0437076AV4-487-0182727650-BDCOR-__A [121913] A Table info 20190116 CC
6   CT01    SRC1    0003114003-400-0179915917-MORTR-AAA [121915] AAA Table info 20190116 CC
7   CT01    SRC1    0008002332-045-0000000001-MORTC-__A [121913] A Table info 20190116 CC
8   CT01    SRC1    091324PBM3-334-0182766417-BDCOR-__A [121913] A Table info 20190116 CC
9   CT01    SRC1    0785592AV8-705-0182772318-BDCOR-BBB [121918] BBB Table info 20190116 CC
10  CT01    SRC2    0097023AE5-557-0182726742-BDCOR-__A [121703] A-FIELD-COMP-20190116
11  CT01    SRC2    0002019609-560-0171464877-MORTR-AAA [121705] AAA-FIELD-COMP-20190116
12  CT01    SRC2    0002018668-560-0171465297-MORTR-AAA [121705] AAA-FIELD-COMP-20190116
13  CT01    SRC2    0003117609-327-0193160029-MORTR-AAA [121705] AAA-FIELD-COMP-20190116
14  CT01    SRC2    0437076AV4-487-0182727650-BDCOR-__A [121703] A-FIELD-COMP-20190116
15  CT01    SRC2    0003114003-400-0179915917-MORTR-AAA [121705] AAA-FIELD-COMP-20190116
16  CT01    SRC2    0008002332-045-0000000001-MORTC-__A [121703] A-FIELD-COMP-20190116
17  CT01    SRC2    091324PBM3-334-0182766417-BDCOR-__A [121703] A-FIELD-COMP-20190116
18  CT01    SRC2    0785592AV8-705-0182772318-BDCOR-BBB [121708] BBB-FIELD-COMP-20190116
```

In the cellname column, i have to consider only the last 3 characters (eg., "__A" , "BBB") and check if the first character after the numbers in tablename column of SRC1 AND SRC2 are matching and display a result.

eg - seq_id 1 and 10 need to be compared as the cellname is same for src1 and src2.

```
seq_id  ID  SOURCE  Cell name   TABLE NAME
1   CT01    SRC1    0097023AE5-557-0182726742-BDCOR-__A [121913] A Table info 20190116 CC
10  CT01    SRC2    0097023AE5-557-0182726742-BDCOR-__A [121703] A-FIELD-COMP-20190116
```

here the last character in cellname column is '__A' i.e., 'A'. If it is matching with the beginning character of tablename column (ignoring the number within []) of both the rows, then the result is pass. in this case, we have 'A' as the first character, hence the result will be 'pass'

```
seq_id  ID  SOURCE  Cell name                        result
1   CT01    SRC1    0097023AE5-557-0182726742-BDCOR-__A   PASS
```

this is something that i am trying to get and since it looks too complicated for me, am totally stuck. Please help.

Comment: It is not clear to me what has to be done with the last 3 characters of the cell name, since you are comparing one character of the table name in 2 matching rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to compare the last 3 characters of Cell Name with the underscores removed to the first part of the table name following the first blank space.

To get the last three characters less any underscores you can use this function `trim(substr("Cell name",-3),'_')` which you can use in a regular expression against the Table name to check for matches.

```
select seq_id
     , ID
     , SOURCE
     , Cell_name
     , case when regexp_like( table_name
                            , '^[^\w]* ' ||
                              ltrim(substr(cell_name,-3),'_') ||
                              '[- ]')
            then 'PASS'
            else 'FAIL'
       end result
  from YourData
```

As with some of the other response to ensure both SRC1 and SRC2 match you can do a self join and add a second condition in the case statement:

```
select src1.seq_id
     , src1.ID
     , src1.SOURCE
     , src1.Cell_name
     , case when regexp_like(src1.table_name,'^[^\w]* '
                             ||ltrim(substr(src1.cell_name,-3),'_')
                             ||'[- ]')
             and regexp_like(src2.table_name,'^[^\w]* '
                             ||ltrim(substr(src2.cell_name,-3),'_')
                             ||'[- ]') 
            then 'PASS'
            else 'FAIL'
       end result
  from YourData src1
  join YourData src2
    on src1.cell_name = src2.cell_name
   and src1.source = 'SRC1'
   and src2.source = 'SRC2'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the case statement while applying join between same table to compare the values, is this what you are looking for?

```
select a.*,
case
    when substr(a.cell_name,length(a.cell_name)-2,3)='__A' and substr a.table_name,10,2)='A ' then 'PASS'
    when substr(a.cell_name,length(a.cell_name)-2,3)=substr(a.table_name,10,3) then 'PASS'
    else 'FAIL'
end as Result
from have a
inner join have b
on a.cell_name=b.cell_name
and a.seq_id<>b.seq_id
and a.source='SRC1';
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the following test expression can be used to represent your business rule :

```
REGEXP_LIKE( 
    cellname, 
    '^[^a-zA-Z]*' || REGEXP_SUBSTR( tablename, '[a-zA-Z]{1,3}$' ) 
)
```

The regexp checks of `tablename` follows the following spec :

- any number of  non-alphabetic character at the beginning of the string a(specifically, that will allow strings starting with `'[1234...] '`)
- followed by the last alphabetic character(s) found in `cellname`, with at least one character and maximum of 3 characters (hence, `'__A'` becomes `'A'`, while `'AAA'` remains `'AAA'`).

In your query, that should give :

```
select t1.*,
CASE 
    WHEN 
            REGEXP_LIKE( t1.cellname, '^[^a-zA-Z]*' || REGEXP_SUBSTR( t1.tablename, '[a-zA-Z]{1,3}$' ) ) 
        AND REGEXP_LIKE( t2.cellname, '^[^a-zA-Z]*' || REGEXP_SUBSTR( t2.tablename, '[a-zA-Z]{1,3}$' ) ) 
    THEN 'pass'
    ELSE 'fail'
END result
FROM mytable t1
INNER JOIN mtable t2 ON t1.cell_name = t2.cell_name AND t2.source = 'SC2'
WHERE t1.source='SRC1';
```